# Pandocs: Md to pdf, support of html-style colors?

Tags: html, pdf, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a .md to pdf that contains both html-style colors:

```
<span style="color:#3297A5">**Like this**</span>
```

and math:

```
$$
J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2m} [\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{(i)})-y^{(i)})^2 + \
lambda\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\theta_j^2)].
$$
```

using

```
pandoc -s -o test.pdf test.md
```

outputs formatting and math fine, but no colors. Using this online md to 
pdf tool http://www.markdowntopdf.com/ i get the colors right, but not 
the math, which indicates that md to pdf conversion of html-style colors is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use CSS to change colors, you'll have to use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org) instead of LaTeX, e.g.

```
$ pandoc input.md --mathjax -t html5 -o output.pdf
```

(or try `--mathml` instead of `--mathjax`, see the [pandoc manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math-rendering-in-html))

Alternatively, you can use a LaTeX template and do layouting there.
For more info, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf

Comment: thanks. Will accept your answer. Different issue: I rolled out a python 2.7 env and ran `conda install -c trentoliphant wkhtmltopdf`. Package installs and is listed, no problem. However when I run `pandoc test.md --mathml -t html5 -o test.pdf` I get `pandoc: wkhtmltopdf not found. wkhtmltopdf is needed for pdf output.` Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `env`, but you can try `pandoc --pdf-engine=/path/to/wkhtmltopdf`